# Can't add Microsoft.Azure.Search 3.0.2 nuget package in VS2017

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-cognitive-search, visual-studio-2017, .net-standard-1.6

I load up a Visual Studio 2017 and create an empty ASP.NET Core console application.  I go to manage nuget packages and "Install-Package Microsoft.Azure.Search" and get the following error:

Install-Package : One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Microsoft.Azure.Search
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Install-Package : Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'vs2017search'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Microsoft.Azure.Search
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

No matter if I try this from .NET Core 1.1 or a NETStandard1.4, 1.5 or 1.6 project I get a similar error.

Adding this package in VS2015 works fine.
Interestingly if I create a ASP.NET Core Console application in VS2015, add the nuget package, upgrade to .NET Core 1.1 and then open it up in VS2017 and do a one way convert it seems to work.

Anyone else experiencing the same or similar and have a solution?

Comment: Are you able to repro this with other Azure client libraries with the package name prefix Microsoft.Azure, or just with Microsoft.Azure.Search? If you try to add a reference to Microsoft.Spatial to your app, do you get the same error?

Comment: I get the same or similar error when I add the following:
Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs 1.0.7
Micsosoft.Azure.

Comment: I get the same or similar error when I add the following:
Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs 1.0.7
Microsoft.Azure.Management.Resources v2.20.1-preview
Microsoft.Spatial v7.0.0
Microsoft.Azure.Management.Storage.Fluent v1.0.0-beta4-1

The following work:
Micsosoft.Azure.Management.Storage v6.0.0-preview
Microsoft.Azure.Management.Authorization v2.4.2-preview
... (others removed for brevity)
Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core v1.0.0

I got one of my colleagues to try the same thing and he has the same experience so looks like it is a VS2017RC /Nuget 4.0 related issue.

Comment: For Microsoft.Azure.Search it shows the following error in VS2017:
Install-Package : Package Microsoft.Spatial 6.15.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1). Package Microsoft.Spatial 6.15.0 supports:
 - dnx451 (DNX,Version=v4.5.1)
  - dnxcore50 (DNXCore,Version=v5.0)
... (others shown removed for brevity)

It doesn't show this error message in .NET Core 1.1 console app in VS2015

Comment: This could be a bug either in VS2017 or in the way some of the Azure packages are built. I recommend opening an issue here as a starting point: https://github.com/azure/azure-sdk-for-net

Comment: You can also file an issue here for Microsoft.Spatial: https://github.com/OData/odata.net

Comment: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/2732
https://github.com/OData/odata.net/issues/751

Comment: Thanks for filing those issues. I'll make sure the right people are aware of them.